# How to transfer/export code collapse information in Adobe Dreamweaver?

Tags: export, dreamweaver

A question for a true superuser. Where is information about code collapsing of Adobe Dreamweaver stored, and how can it be exported/copied to another machine?

*Background:*

*There are files, some with over 20k lines of code, all with carefully collapsed code parts for easy navigation. Re-collapsing everything on another machine is a huge time consumer.*

Comment: If you files are that long, you may want to look into splitting them. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I'm the super user. Found this folder:

```
%AppData%\Adobe\Dreamweaver CS6\en_US\Configuration\CodeCollapse\cache\
```

Close the Dreamweaver, copy the files and enjoy saved time eating donuts!

*Note: Directory names may vary per version and language.*